# Optimizing unboxed array operations in Haskell

Tags: optimization, performance, array, haskell

Consider this simplified code which successively permutes array elements:

```
import Data.Word
import Data.Bits
import Data.Array.Unboxed
import Data.Array.Base
import Data.Array.ST

test3 :: UArray Int Word32 -> UArray Int Word32
test3 arr = arr `seq` runSTUArray (change arr) where
    change a' = do
        a <- thaw a'
        x0 <- unsafeRead a 0
        x1 <- unsafeRead a 1
        unsafeWrite a 0 (x1 + 1)
        unsafeWrite a 1 (x0 - 1)
        return a

test4 :: (Word32, Word32) -> (Word32, Word32)
test4 (x, y) = x `seq` y `seq` (y + 1, x - 1)

apply :: Int -> (Int -> a -> a) -> a -> a
apply n f v0 = n `seq` v0 `seq` applyLoop 0 v0 where
    applyLoop i v
        | i == n - 1 = res
        | otherwise = applyLoop (i + 1) res
        where res = f i v

main :: IO ()
main = let arr = listArray (0, 1) [0, 1] :: UArray Int Word32
    in print $ apply 10000000 (\_ x -> x `seq` test3 x) arr
```

On my machine, with `ghc 7.4.2` and `-O3` flag the version with `test4` (plain tuples) shows ~10 times better performance then the version with `UArray` (also, according to the profiler, `UArray` version has total allocation of ~1.5 Gb). Are there any other optimizations I could do? I'd prefer to use the array version, because it will be more convenient in the real application.

Comment: `applyLoop` is not strict in either of its accumulators.  You might just be getting lucky with the strictness analyzer when using `test4`.  Also, `-O2` is the highest optimization level, although `ghc` seems to silently accept any optimization level.

Comment: Will writing ``where res = i `seq` v `seq` f i v`` make ``applyLoop`` strict (I know I have ``seq``s all over the place, I still have little intuition about strictness analyzer abilities)? It does not seem to have any effect on the performance.

Comment: Actually, what I had in mind was something like ``i `seq` v `seq` applyLoop (i + 1) res``, but that doesn't help either.  I'll post more details in an answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Okay, first let's establish a baseline. I'm on a 32-bit system now, so the allocation figures and also the timings are somewhat different than on a 64-bit system, but the trends are mostly the same. To see what we deal with, let's not compile for profiling, but just plain with optimisations (`-O2`).

I have created [a repository](https://bitbucket.org/dafis/arrayswaps) with all versions of the code I ran. I took the liberty and removed all superfluous `seq`s, and slightly changed `applyLoop`, to

```
applyLoop i v
    | i == n    = v
    | otherwise = applyLoop (i + 1) $ f i v
```

which changes the result if `apply` is initially called with a zero argument (the new one immediately returns the original argument, while the old looped until `i` reaches `-1` after wrap-around of the counter), but for positive arguments the semantics remain unchanged. For very small positive `n`, the one extra comparison the new version does *might* make a measurable difference if `f` is inlined and trivial, but for nontrivial `n` or `f`, the extra comparison is negligible, and the new version avoids code duplication that happens with the old.

That gives

```
$ ./test3 +RTS -s
array (0,1) [(0,0),(1,1)]
    560,049,112 bytes allocated in the heap
        32,160 bytes copied during GC
        42,632 bytes maximum residency (2 sample(s))
        22,904 bytes maximum slop
            1 MB total memory in use (0 MB lost due to fragmentation)

                                    Tot time (elapsed)  Avg pause  Max pause
Gen  0      1083 colls,     0 par    0.02s    0.02s     0.0000s    0.0001s
Gen  1         2 colls,     0 par    0.00s    0.00s     0.0002s    0.0002s

INIT    time    0.00s  (  0.00s elapsed)
MUT     time    1.35s  (  1.35s elapsed)
GC      time    0.02s  (  0.02s elapsed)
EXIT    time    0.00s  (  0.00s elapsed)
Total   time    1.37s  (  1.37s elapsed)

%GC     time       1.3%  (1.3% elapsed)

Alloc rate    415,944,041 bytes per MUT second

Productivity  98.6% of total user, 98.4% of total elapsed
```

in contrast to

```
$ ./test4 +RTS -s
(0,1)
        47,492 bytes allocated in the heap
        1,756 bytes copied during GC
        42,632 bytes maximum residency (1 sample(s))
        18,808 bytes maximum slop
            1 MB total memory in use (0 MB lost due to fragmentation)

                                    Tot time (elapsed)  Avg pause  Max pause
Gen  0         0 colls,     0 par    0.00s    0.00s     0.0000s    0.0000s
Gen  1         1 colls,     0 par    0.00s    0.00s     0.0002s    0.0002s

INIT    time    0.00s  (  0.00s elapsed)
MUT     time    0.04s  (  0.04s elapsed)
GC      time    0.00s  (  0.00s elapsed)
EXIT    time    0.00s  (  0.00s elapsed)
Total   time    0.04s  (  0.04s elapsed)

%GC     time       0.5%  (0.6% elapsed)

Alloc rate    1,182,455 bytes per MUT second

Productivity  98.9% of total user, 103.1% of total elapsed
```

from `test4`. The difference is enormous. Well, let's look at the core to find out why, and how we can reduce it.

First, the core for using `test4`:

```
Rec {
Main.main_$s$wapplyLoop [Occ=LoopBreaker]
  :: GHC.Prim.Int#
     -> GHC.Prim.Word#
     -> GHC.Prim.Word#
     -> (# GHC.Word.Word32, GHC.Word.Word32 #)
[GblId, Arity=3, Caf=NoCafRefs, Str=DmdType LLL]
Main.main_$s$wapplyLoop =
  \ (sc :: GHC.Prim.Int#)
    (sc1 :: GHC.Prim.Word#)
    (sc2 :: GHC.Prim.Word#) ->
    case sc of wild {
      __DEFAULT ->
        Main.main_$s$wapplyLoop
          (GHC.Prim.+# wild 1)
          (GHC.Prim.plusWord# sc2 (__word 1))
          (GHC.Prim.minusWord# sc1 (__word 1));
      10000000 -> (# GHC.Word.W32# sc1, GHC.Word.W32# sc2 #)
    }
end Rec }
```

You can't beat that without short-cutting. You get a tight loop using only unboxed values in registers, it does no allocation. But note that `seq`ing `x` and `y` in `test4` is necessary here to aid the strictness analyser. Without it, you get a loop using boxed `Word32`s building up huge thunks. The `seq`s that originally were in `apply` resp. in the function `` (\_ x -> x `seq` testN x) `` passed to it make no difference whatsoever.

So, we have a lean and mean unboxed loop to aim for, and a sluggish alternative allocating tons. What is allocating so much, and taking so much time there?

The `applyLoop` worker in this case begins with

```
case GHC.ST.runSTRep
       @ (Data.Array.Base.UArray GHC.Types.Int GHC.Word.Word32)
       (\ (@ s) (s :: GHC.Prim.State# s) ->
          let {
            n# [Dmd=Just L] :: GHC.Prim.Int#
            [LclId, Str=DmdType]
            n# = GHC.Prim.sizeofByteArray# ww4 } in
          case GHC.Prim.newByteArray# @ s n# s of _ { (# ipv, ipv1 #) ->
          case {__pkg_ccall array-0.4.0.1 memcpy forall s.
                              GHC.Prim.MutableByteArray# s
                              -> GHC.Prim.ByteArray#
                              -> GHC.Prim.Word#
                              -> GHC.Prim.State# GHC.Prim.RealWorld
                              -> (# GHC.Prim.State# GHC.Prim.RealWorld, GHC.Prim.Addr# #)}
```

allocating a new `ByteArray#` - which is pretty fast, GHC's runtime is very good at such things, but nevertheless, 10 million allocations sum up to non-negligible time - and copying the contents of the old array over. The `__pkg_ccall` is a quite fast C call, but it is considerably slower than a Haskell call, and calling over to C for copying 8 bytes is wasteful (the call takes much longer than the copying). I think - though I can't verify at the moment - that on a 64-bit system that is done without calling out to C, which would be much faster. Replacing the `thaw` with a manual copying loop for an `unsafeNewArray_` of the appropriate size (manual_copy.hs) brings down the time to 0.65 seconds - but increases the allocation figures:

```
$ ./manual_copy +RTS -s
array (0,1) [(0,0),(1,1)]
    760,049,112 bytes allocated in the heap
        41,424 bytes copied during GC
        42,632 bytes maximum residency (2 sample(s))
        22,904 bytes maximum slop
            1 MB total memory in use (0 MB lost due to fragmentation)

                                    Tot time (elapsed)  Avg pause  Max pause
Gen  0      1469 colls,     0 par    0.02s    0.02s     0.0000s    0.0001s
Gen  1         2 colls,     0 par    0.00s    0.00s     0.0003s    0.0003s

INIT    time    0.00s  (  0.00s elapsed)
MUT     time    0.62s  (  0.63s elapsed)
GC      time    0.02s  (  0.02s elapsed)
EXIT    time    0.00s  (  0.00s elapsed)
Total   time    0.64s  (  0.65s elapsed)

%GC     time       3.3%  (3.2% elapsed)

Alloc rate    1,226,997,169 bytes per MUT second

Productivity  96.6% of total user, 95.3% of total elapsed
```

Note that it would be different for a large array, then calling to `memcpy` of the C standard library would pay off.

Using `unsafeThaw` here (unsafeThaw.hs) avoids allocating new `ByteArray#`s (the underlying raw arrays that carry the payload of `UArray`s) each iteration, and the involved copying, so it unsurprisingly speeds up the program, and reduces allocation:

```
$ ./unsafeThaw +RTS -s
array (0,1) [(0,0),(1,1)]
    400,049,112 bytes allocated in the heap
        27,596 bytes copied during GC
        42,632 bytes maximum residency (2 sample(s))
        22,904 bytes maximum slop
            1 MB total memory in use (0 MB lost due to fragmentation)

                                    Tot time (elapsed)  Avg pause  Max pause
Gen  0       764 colls,     0 par    0.01s    0.01s     0.0000s    0.0001s
Gen  1         2 colls,     0 par    0.00s    0.00s     0.0003s    0.0003s

INIT    time    0.00s  (  0.00s elapsed)
MUT     time    0.28s  (  0.28s elapsed)
GC      time    0.01s  (  0.01s elapsed)
EXIT    time    0.00s  (  0.00s elapsed)
Total   time    0.29s  (  0.29s elapsed)

%GC     time       4.4%  (4.3% elapsed)

Alloc rate    1,448,146,787 bytes per MUT second

Productivity  95.5% of total user, 95.6% of total elapsed
```

So the speedup is about 4.5× compared to the original - not bad, but still a *far* cry from the `test4` time - and the allocation is reduced by 160 million bytes (10 million times 8 bytes for the two `Word32` plus 8 for bookkeeping [size] of the `ByteArray#`), but it is still huge.

That is because

```
of _ { (# ipv4, ipv5 #) ->
(# ipv4,
    Data.Array.Base.UArray
    @ GHC.Types.Int @ GHC.Word.Word32 ww1 ww2 ww3 ipv5 #)
}
```

in each iteration it creates a new `UArray Int Word32`. It allocates a new `UArray` constructor, and pointers to the components, lower bound, upper bound, number of elements and the `ByteArray#`. We can avoid that by returning the argument array - after we sneakily changed the contents of its `ByteArray#` (unsafeThaw2.hs):

```
test3 :: UArray Int Word32 -> UArray Int Word32
test3 arr = runST (change arr) where
    change a' = do
        a <- Data.Array.Unsafe.unsafeThaw a' :: ST s (STUArray s Int Word32)
        x0 <- unsafeRead a 0
        x1 <- unsafeRead a 1
        unsafeWrite a 0 (x1 + 1)
        unsafeWrite a 1 (x0 - 1)
        return a'
```

which results in

```
$ ./unsafeThaw2 +RTS -s
array (0,1) [(0,0),(1,1)]
    80,049,100 bytes allocated in the heap
        6,828 bytes copied during GC
        42,632 bytes maximum residency (2 sample(s))
        22,904 bytes maximum slop
            1 MB total memory in use (0 MB lost due to fragmentation)

                                    Tot time (elapsed)  Avg pause  Max pause
Gen  0       151 colls,     0 par    0.00s    0.00s     0.0000s    0.0001s
Gen  1         2 colls,     0 par    0.00s    0.00s     0.0003s    0.0003s

INIT    time    0.00s  (  0.00s elapsed)
MUT     time    0.17s  (  0.17s elapsed)
GC      time    0.00s  (  0.00s elapsed)
EXIT    time    0.00s  (  0.00s elapsed)
Total   time    0.17s  (  0.17s elapsed)

%GC     time       1.7%  (1.7% elapsed)

Alloc rate    480,150,792 bytes per MUT second

Productivity  98.1% of total user, 98.0% of total elapsed
```

another nearly twofold speedup and allocation figures reduced by 80%.

It takes so much longer and allocates so much more than the tight loop mostly because each iteration costs a `GHC.ST.runSTRep`, which is `NOINLINE` and inhibits a worker-wrapper transform of `test3` that would allow cheaper access to the `ByteArray#`.

You can get much better performance if you change the type of `apply` to be monadic, and use a monadic version of `test3`, e.g. (cleanST.hs)

```
import Data.Word
import Data.Array.Unboxed
import Data.Array.ST
import Data.Array.Base
import Control.Monad.ST

test0 :: STUArray s Int Word32 -> ST s (STUArray s Int Word32)
test0 arr = do
    x0 <- unsafeRead arr 0
    x1 <- unsafeRead arr 1
    unsafeWrite arr 0 (x1+1)
    unsafeWrite arr 1 (x0 - 1)
    return arr

applyM :: Monad m => Int -> (Int -> a -> m a) -> a -> m a
applyM n f v0 = do
    let loop i v
            | i < n    = do
                v' <- f i v
                loop (i+1) v'
            | otherwise = return v
    loop 0 v0

main :: IO ()
main = let arr = listArray (0,1) [0,1] :: UArray Int Word32
       in print $ runSTUArray $ do
                    marr <- thaw arr
                    applyM 10000000 (\_ a -> test0 a) marr
```

that comes close to the tight loop:

```
$ ./cleanST +RTS -s
array (0,1) [(0,0),(1,1)]
        49,148 bytes allocated in the heap
        1,756 bytes copied during GC
        42,632 bytes maximum residency (1 sample(s))
        18,808 bytes maximum slop
            1 MB total memory in use (0 MB lost due to fragmentation)

                                    Tot time (elapsed)  Avg pause  Max pause
Gen  0         0 colls,     0 par    0.00s    0.00s     0.0000s    0.0000s
Gen  1         1 colls,     0 par    0.00s    0.00s     0.0002s    0.0002s

INIT    time    0.00s  (  0.00s elapsed)
MUT     time    0.05s  (  0.06s elapsed)
GC      time    0.00s  (  0.00s elapsed)
EXIT    time    0.00s  (  0.00s elapsed)
Total   time    0.06s  (  0.06s elapsed)

%GC     time       0.4%  (0.4% elapsed)

Alloc rate    905,470 bytes per MUT second

Productivity  99.2% of total user, 97.3% of total elapsed
```

but is of course still slower because the array reads and writes go to the L1 cache, while `test4` operated completely in registers.

If you don't want to change the type of `apply`, I know no clean way of coming close to the performance of the tight loop.

If you are prepared to get your hands really dirty, you can use low-level primitives (low_level.hs),

```
{-# LANGUAGE MagicHash, UnboxedTuples, BangPatterns #-}

import Data.Word
import Data.Array.Unboxed
import Data.Array.Base
import GHC.Base

test3 :: UArray Int Word32 -> UArray Int Word32
test3 arr = change arr where
    swp mbarr s =
        case readWord32Array# mbarr 0# s of
          (# s1, w0 #) ->
            case readWord32Array# mbarr 1# s1 of
              (# s2, w1 #) ->
                case writeWord32Array# mbarr 0# (w1 `plusWord#` 1##) s2 of
                  s3 -> writeWord32Array# mbarr 1# (w0 `minusWord#` 1##) s3
    change arr@(UArray _ _ _ ba)
        = case swp (unsafeCoerce# ba) realWorld# of
            !s -> arr
```

which gives more or less the same figures as `cleanST`,

```
$ ./low_level +RTS -s
array (0,1) [(0,0),(1,1)]
        49,112 bytes allocated in the heap
        1,756 bytes copied during GC
        42,632 bytes maximum residency (1 sample(s))
        18,808 bytes maximum slop
            1 MB total memory in use (0 MB lost due to fragmentation)

                                    Tot time (elapsed)  Avg pause  Max pause
Gen  0         0 colls,     0 par    0.00s    0.00s     0.0000s    0.0000s
Gen  1         1 colls,     0 par    0.00s    0.00s     0.0002s    0.0002s

INIT    time    0.00s  (  0.00s elapsed)
MUT     time    0.05s  (  0.06s elapsed)
GC      time    0.00s  (  0.00s elapsed)
EXIT    time    0.00s  (  0.00s elapsed)
Total   time    0.06s  (  0.06s elapsed)

%GC     time       0.4%  (0.4% elapsed)

Alloc rate    928,001 bytes per MUT second

Productivity  99.0% of total user, 95.1% of total elapsed
```

and more-or-less equivalent core (`cleanST`'s is cleaner), but is really as dirty as it looks. I cannot recommend going down that route except in extreme circumstances.

---

Note: new (better) timings, the machine was busier when the original runs were made

Comment: I'm having trouble following your steps, Daniel. If you could hpaste each code variant used on each step, it would probably help a great deal. If you still have them. :) If not, no matter.

Comment: Urk. I'll try to reconstruct as good as possible. Will take a bit.

Comment: and you say you changed it to `ByteArray#`, but the `test3` that follows is tagged with `test3 :: UArray Int Word32 -> UArray Int Word32`... ?

Comment: so is it correct to say that while the original function did 10 million thaws and freezes, your monadic version does just one thaw (and doesn't even bother with unsafeThaw) and then does a 10 million loop *inside* the ST monad? It does make perfect sense for it to perform that much better! :)

Comment: @Will [here is a repo](https://bitbucket.org/dafis/arrayswaps) with as far as I remember all versions. I'll reply to the following comments in a moment.

Comment: @Will No, I didn't change it to `ByteArray#`, nor did I say so, I think. A `ByteArray#` is what bears a `UArray`'s payload. In the second `unsafeThaw` version, we return the `UArray` we got as argument, but in the meantime changed the contents of its (typo there in the answer) `ByteArray#`.

Comment: @Will Yes, `test0` does just one `thaw` (and that I allow to copy, in case something wants to retain the original, for one `thaw` it doesn't make much of a difference). And since we then only have one `runST(UArray)`, we don't run into the `runSTRep` fence on every iteration, so GHC can inline and optimise it better. The reduction from 400 M to 80 M alloc between the two `unsafeThaw` versions is because the first (with `return a`) allocates a new `UArray` constructor (plus the three pointers to the two bounds and the element count), which the second (with `return a'`) doesn't.

Comment: got it! Thanks a lot for all the code and explanations!

Comment: two more (last!) questions (remarks, really) at  http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/8284/discussion-between-will-ness-and-daniel-fischer

Comment: Wow, thank you for such detailed explanation! Especially for the step with moving the loop inside the monad; I'll be aware of this possibility in the future.

Comment: This answer is underrated!

Answer (score 1):

So I profiled your code using the `-prof -auto-all -caf-all` options at first and then ran it with `./arr +RTS -p`, which generates the `arr.prof` file.  It gave me the following measurements:

```
    Sun Apr  7 20:16 2013 Time and Allocation Profiling Report  (Final)

       arr +RTS -p -RTS

    total time  =       10.42 secs   (10419 ticks @ 1000 us, 1 processor)
    total alloc = 14,400,052,608 bytes  (excludes profiling overheads)

COST CENTRE         MODULE  %time %alloc

apply.applyLoop     Main     32.9    0.0
test3               Main     30.7   55.6
test3.change        Main     21.3   44.4
main.\              Main      7.7    0.0
apply.applyLoop.res Main      7.5    0.0
```

All the allocation is occurring in `test3`.  I thought it was because you keep `thaw`ing array, which makes a new copy, but that was not the case.  Replacing `thaw` with `unsafeThaw` and `runSTArray` with the `unsafeFreeze` equivalent did nothing:

```
{-# LANGUAGE RankNTypes #-}

import Data.Word
import Data.Bits
import Data.Array.Unboxed
import Data.Array.Base hiding (unsafeThaw, unsafeFreeze)
import Data.Array.ST
import Control.Monad.ST (ST, runST)

test3 :: UArray Int Word32 -> UArray Int Word32
test3 arr = runST $ change arr where
    change a' = do
        a <- unsafeThaw a' :: forall s . ST s (STUArray s Int Word32)
        x0 <- unsafeRead a 0
        x1 <- unsafeRead a 1
        unsafeWrite a 0 (x1 + 1)
        unsafeWrite a 1 (x0 - 1)
        unsafeFreeze a

test4 :: (Word32, Word32) -> (Word32, Word32)
test4 (x, y) = x `seq` y `seq` (y + 1, x - 1)

apply :: Int -> (Int -> a -> a) -> a -> a
apply n f v0 = n `seq` v0 `seq` applyLoop 0 v0 where
    applyLoop i v
        | i == n - 1 = res
        | otherwise = (applyLoop $! i + 1) $! res
        where res = f i v

main :: IO ()
main = let arr = listArray (0, 1) [0, 1] :: UArray Int Word32
    in print $ apply 100000000 (\_ x -> x `seq` test3 x) arr
```

So I added more fine grained cost centers to zoom in on which part was the trouble-maker:

```
{-# LANGUAGE RankNTypes #-}

import Data.Word
import Data.Bits
import Data.Array.Unboxed
import Data.Array.Base hiding (unsafeThaw, unsafeFreeze)
import Data.Array.ST
import Control.Monad.ST (ST, runST)

test3 :: UArray Int Word32 -> UArray Int Word32
test3 arr = {-# SCC "runST" #-} runST $ {-# SCC "change" #-} change arr where
    change a' = do
        a <- {-# SCC "unsafeThaw" #-} unsafeThaw a' :: forall s . ST s (STUArray s Int Word32)
        x0 <- {-# SCC "unsafeRead1" #-} unsafeRead a 0
        x1 <- {-# SCC "unsafeRead2" #-} unsafeRead a 1
        {-# SCC "unsafeWrite1" #-} unsafeWrite a 0 (x1 + 1)
        {-# SCC "unsafeWrite2" #-} unsafeWrite a 1 (x0 - 1)
        {-# SCC "unsafeFreeze" #-} unsafeFreeze a

test4 :: (Word32, Word32) -> (Word32, Word32)
test4 (x, y) = x `seq` y `seq` (y + 1, x - 1)

apply :: Int -> (Int -> a -> a) -> a -> a
apply n f v0 = n `seq` v0 `seq` applyLoop 0 v0 where
    applyLoop i v
        | i == n - 1 = res
        | otherwise = (applyLoop $! i + 1) $! res
        where res = f i v

main :: IO ()
main = let arr = listArray (0, 1) [0, 1] :: UArray Int Word32
    in print $ apply 100000000 (\_ x -> x `seq` test3 x) arr
```

... but that just gave even more confusing results.  It says that `change` is the bottle-neck, but as far as I can tell, `change` is just the bind for `ST`, which should be just as fast as the `IO` monad's bind (which is fast).

```
        Sun Apr  7 20:39 2013 Time and Allocation Profiling Report  (Final)

           arr +RTS -p -RTS

        total time  =       29.24 secs   (29237 ticks @ 1000 us, 1 processor)
        total alloc = 26,400,052,608 bytes  (excludes profiling overheads)

COST CENTRE         MODULE    %time %alloc

test3.change        Main       45.4   15.2
apply.applyLoop     Main       12.1    0.0
change              Main        6.8   15.2
unsafeFreeze        Main        6.3   24.2
unsafeThaw          Main        6.2   24.2
unsafeRead1         Main        5.0   12.1
runST               Main        4.9    0.0
unsafeWrite2        Main        4.3    9.1
apply.applyLoop.res Main        2.9    0.0
test3               Main        2.7    0.0
main.\              Main        2.7    0.0
```

So I'm sort of at a loss at this point for how to optimize it further, but perhaps somebody else can build off of this.